# Annotation EnableAutoConfiguration does not work for spring boot 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot

No beans get created when I use EnableAutoConfuguation for a self made plugin. If downgrade from spring boot 3.x to 2.7x it works as expected.

The annotation is not deprecated or  deleted for spring-boot 3. So is it a bug or is there a new way and they just forgot depreciation?

Comment: There is a new way as of Spring 2.6/2.7 so read the documentation on how to write your own auto configuration and register it.

Comment: But it works perfectly in up to 2.7

Comment: Hence the documentation that it doesn't work anymore in 3.0. 2.7 was the migration (both old and new working with the old issuing a warning that is was deprecated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution through https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7-Release-Notes#new-autoconfiguration-annotation
Here is described how to setup spring factory the new way.

EnableAutoConfiguration is by mistake not deleted